# Order a list coming from model's Meta option in a @property

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have this model:

```
class Author(models.Model):
class Meta:
    app_label = 'myapp'

surname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
firstname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
extrainfo = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return u"{0} {1} {2}".format(self.firstname,
                                 self.surname,
                                 self.extrainfo)

@property
def alpha_name(self):
    return u"{0}, {1} {2}".format(self.surname, self.firstname, self.extrainfo)

    class Meta:
        ordering = [self.surname]

class Source(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        app_label = "bassculture"

    short_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author = models.ForeignKey("myapp.Author", blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               related_name="sources")
```

View:

```
def SourceList(request):
    sources = Source.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'source/source_list.html', {'sources': sources})
```

Template:

```
    {% for source in sources %}

    <tr>
        <td>{{ source.author.alpha_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ source.short_title }}</a></td>
        <td>{{ source.date }}</td>

    </tr>
```

In the template I'd like the `alpha_name` to be ordered by surname. As you can see I did put the `class Meta: ordering = ...` in my Author model. Nevertheless, the template renders the list of authors ordered by id (the default ordering, I suppose). How can I order it via the model/view? I know about the `|dictsort` tag (`{% for source in sources|dictsort:"author.alpha_name" %}` does the trick). I'd like to have the model or the view sort the ordering though, reducing the template's logic to a minimum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately you're going to need to order the queryset by those fields in that view when you generate the queryset. You can only have one default ordering field.

```
Source.objects.all().order_by('author__surname', 'author__firstname')
```